# How do I implement a legacy TCP/IP service in WCF and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, legacy

I have a legacy TCP/IP service which listens for a message in a proprietary format on a socket.

When the service receives the message, it processes it and replies with a message in a similar format, (classic request/reply situation).

We cannot change the client calling the legacy service and we want to replace the legacy service with a new one hosted in IIS using WCF and C#.

How do I implement this in WCF? Is it even possible to make WCF understand the proprietary message format? If not then any alternatives to WCF? I have flexibility here but must use C# and .NET.

Comment: Try the TcpClient class

Comment: Perhaps something like 'How to implement an asynchronous socket in C#'? 

http://www.infoworld.com/article/3081443/application-development/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-socket-in-c.html

Comment: Thank you Simply G, that's certainly a possibility. However would prefer to host this in IIS and not a console app...

Comment: You can't implement this in WCF without going through a lot of pain. I would look at a custom client implementation similar to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Came across this: http://www.supersocket.net/, anyone had experience with it? Seems to be exactly what I need if I can't use WCF...